# How can I query only the records that have a related list?

Tags: soql, batch

I am trying to do batch that will summarize  TotalPrice fields in all OpportunityLineItem records for every Opportunity that exists in org.

I guess query only the Opportunities that have related OpportunityLineItem list would be much more efficient than skipping the ones that dosen't later in the code.

However I can't figure out how to do that and if its event possible.
Here is example of what I tried :

```
SELECT Id, Name, Products_Amount_Sum__c, (SELECT Id, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE OpportunityLineItems != null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a sub-query filter:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Products_Amount_Sum__c, 
  (SELECT Id, TotalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem)
```